# How I can fire a click event on the label(dataset) and pass its value?

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to trigger the label ("Other", "Minor") or value of a clicked dataset (so later connect is to the particular URL) but the only thing I can retrieve at that moment is `index` and `datasetIndex`.

I'm trying to use the same principle as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45452890/chartjs-how-to-get-from-mulitiple-dateset-which-dataset-bar-is-clicked)

Here is my code:

```js
var ctx = $('#open_chart');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [1, 5],
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue'],
      weight: 1
    }],
    labels: ['Minor', 'Other']
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Title',
      position: 'bottom',
      fontSize: 15,
      fontColor: '#000000'
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
onHover: function(event, chartElement) {
  event.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
    },
onClick: function(e) {
// var pie = this.getElementAtEvent(e)[0];
var pieNotCorrect = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
var pie = this.getElementAtEvent(e)[0];
console.log(pie)
console.log(pieNotCorrect)
var index = pie._index;
var datasetIndex = pie._datasetIndex;
 
// check which part is clicked
if (index == 0 && datasetIndex == 0) alert('First BAR Clicked!');
}
 }
   });



var newDataset = {
  data: [1, 3, 5],
  backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'],
  label: 'SubStatuses',
  labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
  weight: 4
};



chart.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
chart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:500px; width:300px">
  <canvas id="open_chart" style="position:absolute;top:150px;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry, I've changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

*Remove below code from your code :*

```
var pieNotCorrect = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
var pie = this.getElementAtEvent(e)[0];
console.log(pie)
console.log(pieNotCorrect)
var index = pie._index;
var datasetIndex = pie._datasetIndex;
```

*And use only below only :*

```
 var pie = this.getElementAtEvent(e)[0];
```

else your code working fine

```js
var ctx = $('#open_chart');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [1, 5],
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue'],
      weight: 1
    }],
    labels: ['Minor', 'Other']
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Title',
      position: 'bottom',
      fontSize: 15,
      fontColor: '#000000'
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
onHover: function(event, chartElement) {
  event.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
    },
onClick: function(e) {
var activePoints = this.getElementsAtEvent(e);

    var selectedIndex = activePoints[0]._index; 
     alert("Label : " + this.data.labels[selectedIndex] + " Value : " + this.data.datasets[0].data[selectedIndex]);
 
   
}
 }
});



var newDataset = {
  data: [1, 3, 5],
  backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'yellow'],
  label: 'SubStatuses',
  labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
  weight: 4
};



chart.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
chart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="chart-container" style="position: relative; height:500px; width:300px">
  <canvas id="open_chart" style="position:absolute;top:150px;" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, but I want to pass a clicked label to the process, passing indexes works fine :)

Comment: @Karen Please check this , I hope this will anwer your question thanks